# How to sortBy in spark using a function?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, bigdata

For example, I want to sort by using the difference of two values in the tuple. How could I do that in Spark?

I want for example something like as follows.

```
rdd.sortBy(_._2._1 - _._2._2)
```

Comment: `rdd.sortBy(r => r._2._1 - r._2._2)`, you can't use underscore more than once or it will be interpreted as two different arguments

Comment: That is awesome. Thanks.

Comment: @AlbertoBonsanto OK :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use underscore more than once or it will be interpreted as two different arguments (and the expected function should only have one). Instead, name the argument and use it twice:

```
rdd.sortBy(r => r._2._1 - r._2._2)
```